# Command codes in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard

In the article [Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 + Play Next Song Hack](http://electrolabgames.com/blog/?p=26) there is a description how to configure a key on Microsoft keyboard.

In the article there is a concrete direction what codes assign for specific operations - namely for Next and Previous track. I wonder how the author knew the codes? Is there specific code for every command Windows understands?

If there is, then please give a link of that table, please.

Comment: There's some good information in this [sample chapter](http://web.archive.org/web/20060412213208/http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/6232.asp#SampleChapter) from an old MS Windows registry guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed the driver, you should have a file

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft IntelliType Pro\mscmdkey.xml`

Which should have an up to date list of the keycodes.

Probably easier, though, is to go here: 
http://xahlee.info/kbd/ms_keyboard/intellitype_registry.html
because that list is tidy.

Note that the page you link to has the DWORD values created in Hex, whereas the list on the page that I've linked to is base 10, so you'll probably need to convert to Hex to create the correct key.

e.g. MEDIA_PREVIOUS_TRACK_COMMAND  == 704 (base 10) == 2c0 (hex).

Interesting to discover that the intellitype key codes are quite different from the standard windows virtual key constants (defined, for isntance here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx ).  Yet to see a decent explanation for that.